# Python web scrapping product price from an ecommerce site

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, e-commerce

Im trying to get the price of this product https://glomark.lk/coconut/p/11624

```
<span id="product-promotion-price">Rs 99.00</span>
```

using this

```
soup = bs(respnse2.content, 'html.parser')
origin = soup.find("span", {"id": "product-promotion-price"})
```

unfortunately getting the element not the price

```
<span id="product-promotion-price"></span>
```

Comment: I took a quick look at it and it appears that the price is filled in later by JavaScript code.  You'll need to parse the page after javascript code has run.  There are a few ways to do that.  But the easiest thing to do if possible is use their JavaScript API directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the network tab you can see that the site makes a API request to get the items price and much more information, here is it coded in python:

```
import requests

url = 'https://glomark.lk/product-page/variation-detail/11624'

headers = {
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'
}

response = requests.request('POST', url, headers=headers).json()

print(f'Price: {response["price"]}')
print(f'All json: {response}')
```